# Laravel Interactive Notifications

Tags: laravel, pusher

I'm trying to figure out an interactive notification system. My app is built with Laravel and I currently use Pusher to broadcast certain events to the client. I will use the same process with a notification system, however, when a notification pops up for a user, I want some styling on it that will remain unless the user either clicks or hovers over the notification.

I know I can do this with Javascript, but what if a user doesn't act on that notification, signs out, and then signs back in. I want that styling to remain intact until the user interacts with that notification.

Would it be best to create a notification controller and whenever a user interacts with that notification, the database record is updated for that specific user? This seems like a lot since the notifications will be public and broadcast to virtually all users...and to have a database record for each user...that could create a TON of records.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this would be a best way but I would setup:

1. A notification model
2. A relationship with the user. (User -
   Notification - Many to Many)
3. Intermediate table to keep notification & user relations.

Notification model can have the following database fields to keep your notification data.

- id
- title
- message
- status

and your intermediate table could have (notification_user table)

- notification_id
- user_id
- read_on (timestamp)
- is_archived (boolen)

You can update of read_on timestamp when a user read the notification so you don't show them all the time. And you can also provide them an option to archive,etc which should be in your pivot table.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is similar to how I thought about setting it up. Do you foresee an issue if a notification is sent out to 1,000 users thus creating 1,000 database records? Seems like this table would be just HUGE.

Comment: If you are using MYSQL and your notification_id is unsigned int the largest value is 4,294,967,295. If it is unsigned bigint largest value is 18,446,744,073,709,551,615. If you get close to these numbers than I guess you can start worrying about that :)

Comment: No problem. Glad it's helpful.

Comment: A follow-up question. Since I'm using Pusher for the real-time feature, is it best to use a public or private channel? The channel will be user-specific most-likely, but should it be private? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with Pusher but it seems like it should be private. https://pusher.com/docs/client_api_guide/client_private_channels I would still double check though.